# Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias com relacionamento polimórficos no Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou quebrando a cabeça a semanas e não consigo resolver este problema.

Estou usando este pacote https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables para utilizar Datables no Laravel com Livewire.

Tenho os models com os seguintes relacionamentos:

**User.php**

```
public function getAdminAttribute()
    {
        return $this->admins->first();
    }

    public function admins()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Admin::class, 'userable');
    }

    public function getCoachAttribute() //permite pegar o $user->coach direto (encapsulamento)
    {
        return $this->coaches->first();
    }

    public function coaches()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Coach::class, 'userable');
    }

    public function getAthleteAttribute()
    {
        return $this->athletes->first();
    }

    public function athletes()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Athlete::class, 'userable');
    }
```

**Athlete.php**

```
public function coach()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Coach::class);
    }

    public function getUserAttribute()
    {
        return $this->users->first();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'userable');
    }
```

**Coach.php**

```
public function athletes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Athlete::class);
    }

    public function getUserAttribute()
    {
        return $this->users->first();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'userable');
    }
```

**E a tabela pivo:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('userables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->morphs('userable'); //nullableMorphs
        });
    }
```

No tabela component do Livewire do pacote:

```
public function query() : Builder
    {
        return Athlete::with(['coach.users:id,name', 'users:id,name'])->where('company_id', $this->companyId);
    }

    public function columns() : array
    {
        return [
            Column::make('Avatar', 'avatar')
                ->format(function(Athlete $model) {
                    return $this->html('<img class="rounded-circle m-0 avatar-sm-table" src="'. asset("images/users/{$model->user->id}/{$model->user->avatar}") .'" alt="avatar">');
                })
                ->excludeFromExport(),
            Column::make('Nome', 'users.name')
                ->searchable()
                ->sortable(/* aqui é o problema */)
                ->format(function(Athlete $model) {
                    return $this->html($model->user->name);
                }),
            Column::make('Treinador', 'coach.users.name')
                ->searchable()
                //->sortable()
                ->format(function(Athlete $model) {
                    return $this->html($model->coach->user->name);
                }),
                Column::make('Ações', 'actions')
                ->format(function(Athlete $model) {
                    return $this->html(
                        '<a href="'. route('athletes.profile', ['uuid' => $model->uuid]) .'" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon m-0 m-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Ver atleta" title="Ver atleta" target="_blank">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-eye font-weight-bold"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="showConfirmation('. $model->uuid .')" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon m-0 m-0 alert-confirm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Desvincular atleta da empresa" title="Desvincular atleta da empresa">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user-times font-weight-bold"></i>
                        </a>'
                    );
                })
                ->excludeFromExport(),
        ];
    }
```

O erro retornado é esse:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `athletes` left join `userables` on `userables`.`userable_id` = `athletes`.`id` left join `users` on `userables`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `users` on `userables`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `company_id` = 1)
```

Deveria ter como criar um *Alias*?, mas acontece que o pacote faz isso automaticamente (estes joins) e não entendi como contornar.
Já tentei inúmeras coisas e não da certo,

Inclusive no trecho comentado ali `aqui é o problema`, no git do pacote, eles dizem para quando precisar contornar algo diferente no sortable(), para fazer ali dentro usando o Builder. No caso eu tentei fazer isso:

```
Column::make('Nome', 'users.name')
                ->searchable()
                ->sortable(function ($builder, $direction) {
                    return $builder->join('userables', 'athletes.id', '=', 'userables.userable_id')
                                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'userables.user_id')
                                ->where('userables.userable_type', '=', Athlete::class)
                                ->orderBy('users.name', $direction);
                } )
                ->format(function(Athlete $model) {
                    return $this->html($model->user->name);
                })
```

Assim não acontece nenhum erro, mas não ordena corretamente pelos nomes.

Alguém consegue me ajudar nisso?